# clock() - same value before and after loop

Tags: c++

I have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << clock() << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int k = i * i;
    }

    cout << clock() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that both `clock()` calls return the same value. If `clock()` returns processor time used by the program, isn't some processor time spent to execute 100 multiplications? In my case, both calls return 0.

I am on Ubuntu, using GCC to compile.

Comment: The loop probably got optimised away, since it does nothing - do something meaningful in the loop (e.g. `cout` something) and you should see a difference.

Comment: Are you using any flags when compiling? Maybe it takes 0 (µs?) to execute, or maybe it's optimized away since you don't use `k`. The latter seems like a good bet. Compilers are (relatively) smart.

Comment: @PaulR I checked by compiling with `-O0` to prevent optimization. Still the same.

Comment: @keyser `g++ -O0 -o cl cl.cpp`. See also my above comment.

Comment: @PerakR: even without optimisation, the loop does very little and so the elapsed time may be too small to be measured - try adding a `cout` to your loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution of `clock` isn't specified; on the earliest
systems where I used it, it was 20 milliseconds (1/50th of
a second, corresponding the line frequence where I live).
Modern Unix requires that `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND` be defined to
`1000000`, but it still doesn't make any requirements concerning
the actual resolution.  And a hundred multiplications, on
a modern machine, will probably not be more than a couple of
microseconds, if that.  Well below the typical resolution of
`clock`.

Plus, of course, the compiler could have optimized the loop completely away, since it has no impact on the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: Thanks, it's probably the resolution since I compiled preventing optimization. Guess I'll go with `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: No matter what you go with, you'll have to deal with its resolution.  There's no such thing as a clock with infinite resolution, and 100 multiplications will push any clock you're likely to encounter.  (The measurements will also be affected by the time it takes to call the functions, and the jitter in this will probably be greater than what it takes to do 100 multiplications.)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Still, `clock_gettime()` does have higher resolution than `clock()`, doesn't it? For anyone else reading this, here are some articles I found helpful [clock problems](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/10/resolution-problems-in-clock/), [clock_gettime](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/).

Comment: @PerakR The resolution in all cases is implementation defined; I would expect `clock` to be based on _one_ of the underlying clocks which you can use with `clock_gettime`, but there could easily be more precise ones.  And regardless of the resolution, you have to take into account the fact that the calls themselves are not zero time, and introduce some jitter.